# Text Shadow and Border in IE9

Tags: css

[This page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/2012/October/family-halloween.html) uses a dashed border-bottom for the h3 Event Address, but in IE9 it's also showing above it.

Here's the CSS:

```
#middle h3, #middle h4 {
border-bottom:1px dashed #CCC;
padding-bottom:12px;
}
```

Also the text-shadow isn't working at all in IE and when the menu items are hovered, a grey border-left appears and wondered how they could be solved.  Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closed the `<h4>` tag after the div was closed

`<div class="event-date"><h4><img src="/images/date.png" alt="event date" /> On 31 October 2012</div>
    </h4>`

Put the `</h4>` before the `</div>`

Comment: For IE you'll need to make a "hack" for text shadow to work. here's a tutorial how you can achieve that http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/03/10/css-text-shadows-in-internet-explorer/